# Behat formatter - test in IDE

Tags: php, testing, ide, bdd, behat

Is it possible to set up Behat so it displays the results in IDE as pass/fail tests, similarly as PHPUnit tests are displayed? What I want is the graphical output (see the picture below), not just text describing individual scenarios:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use junit output format and load it to your IDE/other application.

http://docs.behat.org/guides/6.cli.html

```
$ behat -f pretty,progress,junit --out ~/pretty.out,,xml
```

In this case, output of pretty formatter will be written to ~/pretty.out file, output of junit formatter will be written to xml folder and progress formatter will just print to console.